# Using a String as Columns

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, select

my first post and my first project with MS Access and VBA, and really coding in general...!

I have an an Excel datatable txlsRegistration with multiple similar columns

```
[LON Option 1 (London Borough)]
[LON Option 1 (Railway Station)]
[BRS Option 1 (Postcode District)]
[BRS Option 1 (Public Transport Hub)]
```

etc

All these fields need to concatenated on the Option number in order to effectively query them later.

So I have a Select Query in Access which concatenates all the same Option number fields together and works fine.

```
SELECT txlsRegistration.ID, [txlsRegistration]![LON Option 1 (London Borough)] & [txlsRegistration]![LON Option 1 (Railway Station)] & [txlsRegistration]![BRS Option 1 (Postcode District)] & [txlsRegistration]![BRS Option 1 (Public Transport Hub)] AS ropOption1
FROM txlsRegistration
```

However, the list of fields is growing, and I want a way to automate the creation of this concatenation in the select query.

I have written a For...Each procedure in VBA called *GetFields* which goes through the table's fields and finds all the Option 1 fields and returns them as a String i.e. `[txlsRegistration]![LON Option 1 (London Borough)] & [txlsRegistration]![LON Option 1 (Railway Station)] & [txlsRegistration]![BRS Option 1 (Postcode District)] & [txlsRegistration]![BRS Option 1 (Public Transport Hub)]`

When I create a new select query using my Function as follows

```
SELECT txlsRegistration.ID, GetFields() AS ropOption1
FROM txlsRegistration
```

it simply returns the actual string against each record. What I want is for the select query to recognise the string as the column names, not a literal string. Is there a way I can do that?

Many thanks on my first venture...!

Comment: No. Table names and field names cannot be dynamic. So, (re)build the SQL from code.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav - are you able to expand on how I would do that?

Comment: Nothing special. SQL is text, so build the SQL as text in code and use it for your query.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate the help but I'm really quite new to this - could you expand on that? I'm trying to concatenate values from multiple fields from a table for any fields which include the string "Option 1"?

Comment: Fields with similar names (XOption1, YOption1, ZOption1) indicates a non-normalized data structure. And if this is 'growing' - fields are periodically added - this is definitely not optimized design. Suggest you re-think design to use normalized related tables. Otherwise, use VBA procedure manipulating DAO QueryDefs collection to modify query objects.

Comment: If this 'growth' exceeds 255 fields in table, you will have to redesign data structure anyway.